# TextureView Align Parent Right Programmatically

Tags: android, layoutparams, textureview

I have a customView extending from TextureView. I want this customView to always align_parent_right.

My method inside customView has the following code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

However, customeView is still aligned left and not right. How can it be change to align right?

Comment: can you post the rest of this method? what are you setting these params on?

Answer (score 0):

Add this way

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.leftViewIdHere);
setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```